# Using IndexedDB/PouchDB for offline caching of external resources such as css and png

Tags: angular, indexeddb, pouchdb, offlineapps

this is my first post so let me know if I do anything incorrectly.

We are working on an angular 2 webapp and we want the capability of working offline for a number of browsers (IE11, Chrome, Mobile Safari). In order to achieve this we have looked into IndexedDB and PouchDB as they allow caching of large amounts of data.

Our situation is as follows. On initialization, we will call an api service that will return us a number of resource files, e.g. a css file and a png file named "styles.css" and "image.png" respectively. We will store these in the DB. We then inject the css into the `<head>` using a `<link>` tag when we show the respective component.

The html would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
...
</html>
```

Inside the styles.css we will have a url to the png:

```
.example-icon .icon
{
    background-image: url("image.png")
}
```

The question is, how do we reference the "styles.css" from the html, and the "image.png" from the "styles.css", when both the "styles.css" and "image.png" are in the IndexedDB/PouchDB.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done automatically - URLs into Indexed DB are not supported ([feature request](https://github.com/w3c/IndexedDB/issues/57)).

On approach would be to store the resources in the database as Blobs. When needed, retrieve the record and use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` to create a temporary URL for it. This URL will not be valid once the page that creates the URL closes, so retrieving the record on each page load will be necessary, but the URL can be used in the page. Note that in your example this would work for the stylesheet link injected into the page, but the `url()` reference inside the stylesheet would need to be yet another Blob URL requiring updating on page load, which makes this even more complicated.

Beyond that, other options include storing everything as strings and using e.g. data: URLs (e.g. you can just embed the image data inside the stylesheet).

With the limitations you list (IE11, etc) the options are fairly restricted. With more modern browsers (latest Chrome and Firefox) the recommended approach would be to use Service Workers and the Cache Storage API; your app would register a service worker and any network request can be intercepted and routed to the cache API. This approach is powerful enough to implement [URLs into Indexed DB](https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/687e7c5914049536f5a3) but once you have these newer APIs you may prefer to use the Cache API anyway.

Comment: Absolutely right, this is what ServiceWorker is designed for. You may want to implement ServiceWorker with an ApplicationCache fallback for Safari/Edge/IE.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Joshua. We have been looking at URL.createObjectURL(blob) and will probably be using that approach. There is also the issue that we are using URL rewrite the rewrite urls that match a regex to a specific port, e.g. localhost/app/test -> localhost:3000/app/test. Not sure if the createObjectURL will cause issues if it only makes the URLs on localhost/objecturl. Got any suggestions?

@nlawson Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't think app cache is sufficiently versatile to be a fallback for ServiceWorker in this use case.